# Floating rectangles when highlighting ListCells

Tags: java, debugging, javafx, fxml

I have a bug that appears in my application whenever I try to add or delete a cell. The bug disappears randomly after I enter some new filtering commands, but reappears if I try adding or deleting a cell again.

For example,

[cells are highlighted correctly when I first open my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJs2a.png)

[But floating highlighted rectangles appear after I enter commands that specifically create new cells or delete existing ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Df6.png)

The code I'm using to set the new styles are as follows:

```
class ModuleListViewCell extends ListCell<Module> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Module module, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(module, empty);

        if (empty || module == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(new ModuleCard(module, getIndex() + 1).getRoot());
            if (module.equals(getCurrentlyShownModule())) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + BACKGROUND_COLOUR + "; "
                        + "-fx-border-color: " + BORDER_COLOUR + "; "
                        + "-fx-border-width: " + BORDER_WIDTH + ";");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use this same code for all of my lists. I am quite certain that the bug lies in the UI, and not the code that selects a cell to highlight (e.g. getCurrentlyShownModule()). However, I cannot seem to figure out the cause for the floating rectangles. I would appreciate all the advice I can get

The code for the .fxml files are as follows:

ModuleListCard.fxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<HBox id="cardPane" fx:id="cardPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <GridPane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10" prefWidth="150" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" minHeight="50" GridPane.columnIndex="0">
            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" right="5" bottom="5" left="15" />
            </padding>
            <HBox spacing="5" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                <Label fx:id="id" styleClass="cell_big_label">
                    <minWidth>
                        <!-- Ensures that the label text is never truncated -->
                        <Region fx:constant="USE_PREF_SIZE" />
                    </minWidth>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="name" text="\$first" styleClass="cell_big_label" />
            </HBox>
            <Label fx:id="identifier" styleClass="cell_small_label" text="\$identifier" />
        </VBox>
    </GridPane>
</HBox>
```

ModuleListPanel.fxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <ListView fx:id="moduleListView" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
</VBox>
```

And here is the CSS file I am using for my project

```css
.background {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
    background-color: #383838; /* Used in the default.html file */
}

.background-2 {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#2a2a2a, 20%);
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #2a2a2a; /* Used in the default.html file */
}

.label {
    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-text-fill: #555555;
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
}

.label-bright {
    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.label-header {
    -fx-font-size: 32pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.text-field {
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
}

.tab-pane {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 1;
    -fx-tab-min-height: 3em;
    -fx-tab-max-height: 3em;
}

.tab-pane .tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-min-height: 0;
    -fx-max-height: 0;
}

.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
}

.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
}

.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab .tab-label {
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
}

.table-view {
    -fx-base: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-control-inner-background: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-table-header-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 5;
}

.table-view .column-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .column-header, .table-view .filler {
    -fx-size: 35;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color:
        transparent
        transparent
        derive(-fx-base, 80%)
        transparent;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 10 1 0;
}

.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-font-size: 20pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color;
}

.split-pane:horizontal .split-pane-divider {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent transparent #4d4d4d;
}

.split-pane {
    -fx-border-radius: 1;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.list-view {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
}

.list-cell {
    -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-graphic-text-gap : 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.list-cell:filled:even {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3e3f;
}

.list-cell:filled:odd {
    -fx-background-color: #515658;
}

.list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #424d5f;
}

.list-cell:filled:selected #cardPane {
    -fx-border-color: #3e7b91;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
}

.list-cell .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.cell_big_label {
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-font-size: 16px;
    -fx-text-fill: #010504;
}

.cell_small_label {
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI";
    -fx-font-size: 13px;
    -fx-text-fill: #010504;
}

.stack-pane {
     -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
}

.pane-with-border {
     -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
     -fx-border-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 10%);
     -fx-border-top-width: 1px;
}

.status-bar {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 30%);
}

.result-display {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-font-size: 13pt;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.result-display .label {
    -fx-text-fill: black !important;
}

.status-bar .label {
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-padding: 4px;
    -fx-pref-height: 30px;
}

.status-bar-with-border {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 30%);
    -fx-border-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 25%);
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}

.status-bar-with-border .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.grid-pane {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 30%);
    -fx-border-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 30%);
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}

.grid-pane .stack-pane {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 30%);
}

.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 50%);
}

.context-menu .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
}

.menu-bar .label {
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
}

.menu .left-container {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

/*
 * Metro style Push Button
 * Author: Pedro Duque Vieira
 * http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/jmetro-windows-8-controls-on-java/
 */
.button {
    -fx-padding: 5 22 5 22;
    -fx-border-color: #e2e2e2;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-text-fill: #d8d8d8;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

.button:pressed, .button:default:hover:pressed {
  -fx-background-color: white;
  -fx-text-fill: #1d1d1d;
}

.button:focused {
    -fx-border-color: white, white;
    -fx-border-width: 1, 1;
    -fx-border-style: solid, segments(1, 1);
    -fx-border-radius: 0, 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 1 1 1 1, 0;
}

.button:disabled, .button:default:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 0.4;
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.button:default {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}

.button:default:hover {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-focus-color, 30%);
}

.dialog-pane {
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.dialog-pane > *.button-bar > *.container {
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.dialog-pane > *.label.content {
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.dialog-pane:header *.header-panel {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 25%);
}

.dialog-pane:header *.header-panel *.label {
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-style: italic;
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 20%);
}

.scroll-bar .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#1d1d1d, 50%);
    -fx-background-insets: 3;
}

.scroll-bar .increment-button, .scroll-bar .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.scroll-bar .increment-arrow, .scroll-bar .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-shape: " ";
}

.scroll-bar:vertical .increment-arrow, .scroll-bar:vertical .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-padding: 1 8 1 8;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .increment-arrow, .scroll-bar:horizontal .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-padding: 8 1 8 1;
}

#cardPane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

#commandTypeLabel {
    -fx-font-size: 11px;
    -fx-text-fill: #F70D1A;
}

#commandTextField {
    -fx-background-color: transparent #383838 transparent #383838;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-color: #383838 #383838 #ffffff #383838;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-font-size: 13pt;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

#filterField, #studentListPanel, #studentWebpage {
    -fx-effect: innershadow(gaussian, black, 10, 0, 0, 0);
}

#resultDisplay .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, #383838, transparent, #383838;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

#tags {
    -fx-hgap: 7;
    -fx-vgap: 3;
}

#tags .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: #3e7b91;
    -fx-padding: 1 3 1 3;
    -fx-border-radius: 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 2;
    -fx-font-size: 11;
}

.label-new {
    -fx-font-size: 14;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-text-fill: #aaa;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.label-title {
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-text-fill: #ccc;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.label-h1 {
    -fx-font-size: 28px;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-text-fill: #aaa;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.default-color0.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #FFC58C; }

.default-color0.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #FFADCA; }
.default-color1.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #BA72E8; }
.default-color2.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #8999FF; }
.default-color3.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #72D7E8; }
.default-color4.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #7DFFAF; }
.default-color5.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #cccccc; }

.chart-title {
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-text-fill: #ccc;
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}

.axis-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #aaa;
}

.chart-pie-label-line {
    -fx-stroke: #aaa;
    -fx-fill: #aaa;
}

.chart-pie-label { /*this is what you need for labels*/
    -fx-fill: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: You should post, at least, the complete `ListCell` implementation; however you are unlikely to get help with this unless others can actually reproduce the issue; so ideally create and post a [mcve]

Comment: @James_D would it suffice to provide a .jar file of my application?

Comment: No; it's unlikely anyone would be careless enough to run a jar file from an unknown stranger (I can probably fairly easily create one that extracts all the passwords and bank account information from your computer, and emails it to me, for example). Besides, the aim is not to provide your actual project, but a simple, clear, example that reproduces the same problem. Anyway, there's a good chance there's enough code in your question to identify the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset the styles if the cell becomes empty, or if your condition becomes false. Therefore, as cells are reused, the style is never cleared. You need:

```
class ModuleListViewCell extends ListCell<Module> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Module module, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(module, empty);

        if (empty || module == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            setGraphic(new ModuleCard(module, getIndex() + 1).getRoot());
            if (module.equals(getCurrentlyShownModule())) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + BACKGROUND_COLOUR + "; "
                        + "-fx-border-color: " + BORDER_COLOUR + "; "
                        + "-fx-border-width: " + BORDER_WIDTH + ";");
            } else {
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logic may not be exactly what you specifically need, but you need to ensure the style is set to the appropriate value under all possible code paths.

As an aside, you shouldn't be creating new UI elements on every call to `updateItem(...)`, which can be called very frequently (e.g. during scrolling). Create the UI component once, and update it from `updateItem()`:

```
class ModuleListViewCell extends ListCell<Module> {

    private final ModuleCard card = new ModuleCard();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Module module, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(module, empty);

        if (empty || module == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            // update card with data...
            card.setModule(module);
            card.setIndex(getIndex() + 1);
            setGraphic(card.getRoot());
            if (module.equals(getCurrentlyShownModule())) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + BACKGROUND_COLOUR + "; "
                        + "-fx-border-color: " + BORDER_COLOUR + "; "
                        + "-fx-border-width: " + BORDER_WIDTH + ";");
            } else {
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

defining the appropriate methods in `ModuleCard`, as required.

Comment: Hi, your solution works perfectly. Thank you so much for your advice!